# Check condition in checkout in Opencart 3.0?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

I am a beginner in OpenCart and Currently, I am using journal theme and I want make some condition that the customers don't allow to checkout if the shopping amount is less than 1000. Is this possible to make in OpenCart 3.0?
If then, which controller, which view should I add code?
**Help me :-(**

Updated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <modification>
    <name>Total Amount Checkout</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <author>Custom</author>
    <link>http://upencart.com</link>
    <code>total_amount_checkout</code>        
      <file error="skip" path="admin/controller/setting/setting.php">  // Do here, Is this the right path that I can make change? [I am using Journal theme]
        <operation error="skip">
           <search><![CDATA[ ******* ]]></search>  // Do here
           <add position="*******"><![CDATA[*******]]></add>  // Do here

        </operation>
      </file>
   <file error="skip" path="catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php">
    <operation error="skip">
        <search><![CDATA[$redirect = '';]]></search> // Do here
        <add position="after"><[CDATA[]]></add> // Do here
    </operation>
</file>
  </modification>
```

In which path and what code should I add? Do something in above code based on my question.

Comment: Use [vqmod](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/administration/vqmod/) and write your own core modification. Alternatively, you could write a totals extension, but all will depend on the UX you want to provide.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Do not use VQMOD if your OC version 3 use OCMOD or events. And you should ask Journal developers how it can be acomplished, because this theme has changed a lot of OC core files.

Comment: @K.B. After using OCMOD or VQMOD or installing OCKMOD extension, How can I do to get the output as mentioned above? Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: OCMOD just only the way how to implement the code to the files. Please post what you have tried and we try to put you on the right way.

Comment: @K.B. I have just added some piece of code and I don't no what to and where to modify code.. Will you help me to solve this ?